# How to change the ClientRect of a form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Please refer to another question here: [Resizing borderless form from different constraints than far edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391135/resizing-borderless-form-from-different-constraints-than-far-edges)

This previous question has been resolved, but I have another similar question. Since I am building a custom shaped form with a different client area, I need to change the ClientRect area of this form. The form has some special drawing of some curved edges and such, but that part's irrelevant. I need to change the ClientRect of the form to represent a new client area where components are allowed to be dropped, and ignore anything put outside of those bounds.

(I have a borderless form, I'm drawing my own border which is a much different size than the standard windows border.)

This solution will kind-of change the way that my previous question works, but that'll be another topic which I'm sure I'll figure out on my own, should be very simple. I just need to be able to properly set this in the first place.

Comment: -1. Please use winforms tag only if you develop for .NET (Delphi 8..2007)

Comment: What you should be asking is how do I set a non-rectangular clipping region on my form?

Comment: components: http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=94

Comment: I would have looked up 'non-rectangular clipping region' if I knew the topic to begin with, isn't that the point of this place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    procedure WmNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
    ..

..

procedure TForm1.WmNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize);
begin
  inherited;
  if Msg.CalcValidRects then begin
    InflateRect(Msg.CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0], -10, -6);
    Msg.Result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Please, carefully read [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize)'s documentation though, including the *remarks* section and also [`NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagnccalcsize_params), as I'm not sure this is what you want. But this is your message..